# Finding out values from Matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Consider two 3 x 3 matrices A and B satisfying $ A = Adj B - B^T $ and $ B = Adj A - A^T $ (where $ C^T $denotes transpose of matrix $C $)

1) If $A $ is non singular, then $(det A)^2 + (det B)^2 $ is equal to?

2) $AB$ is equal to?

Comment: $A+B^T=adj(B)$ and $B+A^T=adj(A)$, but $(A+B^T)^T=B+A^T$, so $adj(B^T)=adj(A)$ and take det on both sides we get $|A|^2=|B|^2$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(adj B)^T$ instead of $(adj B^T)$ ?

Comment: Transpose of adjoint is same as adjoint of transpose

Comment: I didn't knew that. Can you give me its proof

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $$\text{det}(\text{Adj}(A))=(\text{det}(A))^{n-1}$$

and

$$\text{det}(A^{T})=\text{det}(A)$$

Comment: Thanks for answer. Well I know these but I am wondering how can I use them here. i cannot equate determinant of both side since the matrices are in subtraction and I couldn't simplify them. I even tried multiplying both. Or placing value of B from 2nd equation to first but i couldn't get the answer. Any help?